# Sharing of variable between DRL file in 1 kiession

Tags: java, drools, rules

What is the best approach to use to share the variable between 2 DRL file in 1 kie session?

I understand global variable is not an option for me because once the global variable value is assigned, it be shared with other kie session as well.

Comment: Using Global variable is the best approach to share variable across all the rules in a drl File. If you want to share the same variable in another session you have to  `setGlobal` that variable in the other session.

Comment: As @Prog_G mentioned, globals are shared among all the rules in a session. They are not shared (their values) across multiple sessions.

Comment: global will not be shared in another session unless i do setGlobal but when running another DRL file in the same session, then the variable become null again. Anyway to store a variable in same session on multiple DRL file?

Comment: Hi @EstebanAliverti actually my requirement is simple, i just a need a variable that shared between multiple DRL in 1 single session.. what kind of variable that suitable to use?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you call 'variable'.

If the variable is something that you are using to parameterize your rules, and it remains constant through the entire execution of your session, then you can use a [global](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_global). Declare the global in all the DRL files you want to use it (the declaration must be the same (i.e. type and name) in all of your DRL files) and set it value using `ksession.setGlobal(...)` before inserting the facts in your session.

If the variable is something you want to use to communicate data between rules, then the best approach would be to use a specific fact for it. Create a class to hold the information you want to share and insert it as a fact where need it.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Hi @Esteban Aliverti . do you mind share an example how to create a class and insert as a fact for multiple DRL file usages?

Comment: By a fact I mean whatever Java class that you can insert into your session (just like you are already doing)

Comment: By a fact I mean whatever Java class that you can insert into your session (just like you are already doing)   ==> it is working!

Comment: If the variable is something that you are using to parameterize your rules, and it remains constant through the entire execution of your session, then you can use a global.  ===> i tried for the global variable being assign something , the value remains the same or didn't reinitialize when there is a new session ?? I tested it using swagger from different browsers